# Merge variable number of rows in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm new to pandas and working with dataframes. I have a rather simple problem that I think should have a straightforward solution which is not clear to me (and I do not know pandas that well).

So I have many occurrences of rows with same index in my data frame:

```
                     Glucose   Insulin  Carbs
Hour
2018-05-16 06:43:00    156.0       0.0    0.0
2018-05-16 06:43:00      NaN       0.0   65.0
2018-05-16 06:43:00      NaN       7.0    0.0
```

And I would like to merge them to get this, a row which contains all the information available at a given time index:

```
                     Glucose   Insulin  Carbs
Hour
2018-05-16 06:43:00    156.0       7.0   65.0
2018-05-16 06:43:00      NaN       0.0   65.0
2018-05-16 06:43:00      NaN       7.0    0.0
```

Afterwards I would drop all rows which contain NaN in any column to get:

```
                     Glucose   Insulin  Carbs
Hour
2018-05-16 06:43:00    156.0       7.0   65.0
```

The problem is that in the same dataframe I have duplicates with less information, maybe only Carbs or Insulin.

```
                     Glucose   Insulin  Carbs
Hour
2018-05-19 06:15:00      NaN       1.5    0.0
2018-05-19 06:15:00    229.0       0.0    0.0
```

I already know the indices of these entries:

```
bad_indices = _df[ _df.Glucosa.isnull() ].index
```

What I would like to know is if there's like a nice Pythonic way to do such a task (both for the two, and three rows cases).
Maybe a pandas built-in method or something which is semi standard
or at least readable because I don't want to write ugly (and easily breakable)
code that has explicit considerations for each case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can replace `0` to `NaN` and then get first non `NaN` values per group:

```
df = df.mask(df == 0).groupby(level=0).first()
print (df)
                     Glucose  Insulin  Carbs
Hour                                        
2018-05-16 06:43:00    156.0      7.0   65.0
```